# How to manage database schema in "real" project?

Tags: node.js, database, version-control

I'm learning NodeJS and using Prisma to manage my database schema and it's pretty easy.
But i wonder how they manage database in "real" project?
Are they just define schema in .sql file and use git to controll the version of database?

I used Laravel before and manage its database version by using "migration". But I want to know how to do that manually without a framework.

It would be great if you could tell me the process of creating a database and managing its version?
Because I have never worked at IT company before.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: What do you already know? We can only help you if you have done your research.

Comment: In professional environments different teams manage the development, the deployment of the app to dev, stage, test, and prod, so no one single person can have full access to everything. In this scenario each change needs to be communicated properly. For example you need to store and version code in a source code repository (such as git). In every official version there can be new database changes, so these are also versioned as separate SQL files, for each specific version.

Comment: @OwJi Right now i folowing these steps:
- Create an Initial Database Schema Script: init.sql
- Make a Change to the Schema: change1.sql
- Rollback Script: change1.rollback.sql

and use git to control the script version

Comment: @TheImpaler thank you for your reply.
I know these process. But i meant that how do i get control of my database schema properly. In my case, I use NodeJS and Postgresql. How should i organize my project? All the database schema control are just .sql file?

Comment: The SQL files define the table's structure, their columns, and their constraints, etc. These files will be executed in the production environment to get that database ready BY OTHER PEOPLE, not you. Therefore, they need to be tested thoroughly in advance.